# Why is the "&" address operator necessary here?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm doing pointer exercises. Please help me understand it!

so I have this code:

```
int* intPtr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
scanf("%d", intPtr);
printf("%d\n", *intPtr);
```

When I use `scanf()` I don't need the `&` symbol because `intPtr` is already a pointer. Is that correct? So then how come I have to use `&array[i]` in this situation:

```
int number;
scanf("%d", &number);
int* array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*number);
for (int i=0; i<number; i++){
     scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
```

Isn't the `array` variable a pointer already?

Comment: Because `array[i]` isn't a pointer. OTOH you could use `scanf("%d", array + i)`.

Comment: `array` can work like a pointer, but `array[i]` is an int.

Comment: When calling malloc, use the idiom `int *intPtr = malloc(count * sizeof *intPtr);`  That is, do not cast the value, and compute the size of the object rather than the size of the type.

Comment: if `array[i]` is not a pointer then why does this code work? `int** matrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);
        for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
            matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);`  from what I understand in this case `matrix[i]` points to a location where int*col amounts of memory was allocated. I probably got it all wrong. I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 2):

`array` is a pointer, but `array[i]` is not.  What you have in memory is something like this:

```
       int *       int
       +---+       +---+
array: |   | ----> |   | array[0]
       +---+       +---+
                   |   | array[1]
                   +---+
                    ...
                   +---+
                   |   | array[number-1]
                   +---+
```

Each `array[i]` is an object of type `int`, not a pointer.  So, for `scanf` to write a new value to `array[i]`, you must pass an address to that element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what the `[ ]` operator is doing there. When you declare an array you allocate a block of memory big enough to contain your array. You then get the address of the first element in the block. So when you have `int a[10];` you allocate memory for 10 ints and `a` is a pointer to the first one.`[ ]` is an operator that is defined like this: `a[x] == *(a + x)`. So `a[x]` is not a pointer, `a` is. What you want to write is `&array[i]` or `(array + i)`.

Comment: `a` is _converted_ to a pointer (in most expressions) rather than actually being a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the array variable a pointer already?

Yes, the variable `array` is already a pointer, a pointer that points to an array of integers (it points to the first element of the array), so you can substitute (by doing some pointer arithmetic), instead of:

```
     scanf("%d", &array[i]);
```

you can use

```
     scanf("%d", array + i);
```

and then there's no need for the `&` operator.  But `array[i]` is the `i`-esim element of the array, an integer.

`scanf(3)` requires you to pass an address (a reference) and `array[i]`  is not an address, so you need to pass the address of the `i`-esim element of the array, which is `&array[i]`.

Answer (score -3):

The difference is that when you pass `intPtr` just like that, you're passing the pointer itself - that is, not a reference to the pointer and not the value of the pointer, but the pointer in its entirety. This means that you can modify the pointer in `scanf` directly, as if it was declared in the same method or function.

When you're passing `&array[i]`, you're passing a *reference* to the pointer, not the pointer itself. This means that you can access the value of the pointer without having to dereference it first. But it also means that you're limited in how you can modify the pointer - you can't reassign it, for example.

Comment: The `&` operator here is taking the address of an array element. You aren't passing a reference to a pointer.